# DNS wildcard problem

Tags: domain-name-system

Is there a way to match domain.com without using an "@" entry?
It seems "*" entries only match *.domain.com

Answer (score 2):

What is your ultimate goal in eliminating the use of "@"? The @ isn't actually part of DNS; it's just a placeholder in your DNS zone file syntax that means "no hostname here".

Instead of writing (BIND zone file syntax):

```
    @             IN    A    1.2.3.4
```

you can use a fully qualified name on the left:

```
    example.com.  IN    A    1.2.3.4
```

Note that the trailing period after `com.` is critical in this example, since BIND assumes that names written without a trailing period get the current zone name appended to them (so you'd end up with an A record for `example.com.example.com.`, probably not what you want).

Answer (score -3):

I tend to just CNAME `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing that. Records with a CNAME cannot have any other records (including NS and SOA), so it is logically invalid to add a CNAME to domain.com. You may find that it works sometimes, but there are resolvers out there that *will fail* when they encounter this situation. For references, see RFC 1034 section 3.6.2 and RFC 1912 section 2.4.

Comment: yeah, don't do that. :)